# How to display ckeditor in template django with crispy forms?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-crispy-forms

I have installed ckeditor for django and it is displayed in the admin as it should, but how do I make it display in my template.

template

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}{%block content%} {% if user.is_superuser %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {% if error_message %}
                    <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="label-edit" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% else %}
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">404 Not Found</h1>
    {% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

I am using crispy forms. I want the ckeditor to appear on the template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly add {{ form.media }} so it looks like

`{{ form.media }}
{{ form|crispy }}`

Answer (score 1):

in your form class file add the following:

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
```

then you can use the CKEditorWidget like this:

```
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

for more information read the guide on the [git page](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)....

Answer (score 0):

To make CKEditor work outside the admin panel, you have to make sure all form media is present for the editor to work by doing this:

```html
...
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.as_p }}
// or you can use crispy filter: {{ form|crispy }}
// you can specify the exactly field you want e.g form.content
{{ form.content }}
// you can use crispy without any problem: 
{{ form.content|as_crispy_field }}
...
```

sometimes, when using `{{ form.media }}` it wouldn't load the media and show an error (for me it gives me this error: `Object of type PosixPath is not JSON serializable`), so you have to load it manually in the `form.html` file (or whatever you call it e.g: `blog_form.html`) or the `base.html` file via `<script>` tag:

```html
{% load static %}
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

sometimes you have to mention where ckeditor will find its static files via CKEDITOR_BASEPATH in `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_root'

# add this line
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = STATIC_ROOT / "ckeditor" / "ckeditor"
```

---

check out [CKEditor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#outside-of-django-admin) documentation for more